# GPS and PIC16F876A

Tags: pic, gps

I am trying to configure a GPS receiver with PIC16F876A. In the code below i am receiving characters from UART, and checking whether received character is `$`. If condition is true, receive characters and store it in character array `gps` until `,` is seen.

If I type in characters through serial prompt in Linux, code works as it is supposed to.
But if I connect it to the GPS receiver I only get first two characters and LCD will show **OVERRUN**. 
I am new to PIC. 
what should I do??

```
char a, gps[50];
int i, j, k, flag = 0;
void GPS_init()
{
        TXSTA = 0X24; //00100100
        RCSTA = 0X90; //10010000
        SPBRG = 25;
}

char uart_rx()
{
        while(!RCIF);
        //RCIF=0;
        a=RCREG;
        return(a);

}


void GPS()
{
    for(i=0; ;i++)
    {
        a = uart_rx();
        TXREG = a;   //view received data in serial terminal
        while(TRMT == 0);
        data(a); 
        if(OERR == 1)
        {
            command(0Xc0);
            display("OVERRUN"); //Display string to LCD
            CREN = 0;
        }

        if(a == '$')
        {
            gps[0] = '$';
            for(k=1; ;k++)
            {
                gps[k] = uart_rx();
                data(gps[k]);   //display character to LCD
                TXREG = gps[k]; //view received data in serial terminal
                while(TRMT == 0);

                if(gps[k] == ',')
                {
                    gps[k] = '\0';
                    flag = 1;
                    break;      
                }
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    GPS_init();
    LCD_init();
    command(0x80);
    display("Initializing");
    command(0x01);
    GPS();


    while(1)
    {
        command(0XC0);
        display(gps);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The overrun error means that you aren't taking the bytes out of the UART receiver as fast as they are coming in.
My guess would be that the problem is with this code

```
while(TRMT == 0);
```

I assume that this causes execution to pause until the byte put into `TXREG` has actually been transmitted. This pause is what is killing your ability to keep up with the input.

Bottom line is that you shouldn't be trying to do both processes (receiving and transmitting) in lock-step. You need to use a data buffer (e.g., your `gps` array) to allow the two processes to run asynchronously.

Comment: I put received data in TXREG to see how much data I've received. Even with out it am not able to receive desired data.

Comment: Today I configured uart as an interrupt, and receive five character after $, and if they are same as **GPGGA,**,  it would print it out on screen. Even pasting large data as this _gffgjjkgjgjgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjffgjjhgjgjgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfggjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjgjhydfgfgffgjjhgjgjgjffgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjgjhydfgfgffgjjhgjgjgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjgjhydfgfgffgjjhgjgjgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjgjhydfgfgffgjjhgjgjgjffg\nff\n\rvbgfjgjhydfgfgfhgty74332365%%#!#$GPRGA,dgfgjhydfgfgfhgty74332365%%#!#$GPGGA,dgf_ on serial prompt, I could get **$GPGA** to print on serial prompt. But connecting GPS module wold cause OVERRUN error

Comment: There's no way I can comment on that without seeing the new code. Add it to your question.

Comment: I will update that.

Comment: I've commented off `a=TXREG` `while(TRMT==0)` and `data()` lines, but still not working.